# VBA script for outlook to automatically open URLs from message body in a web browser, for all incoming mails

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm pretty new to writing VBA scripts. Actually, I'm trying to write a small VBA script which will go through the newly received email, scan the body of the message and open all the urls(I'm targetting this script for a message which always contains a single URL) in a web browser like IE or FF or Chrome. I tried looking for similar Qs in SO and on Google. I found one here: [How to launch a URL when an email arrives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619079/how-to-launch-a-url-when-an-email-arrives) which is about how to open a URL when an email arrives. But it is always opening a fixed URL and not by going through the message body and picking the URL from there. Also, I found this: [Using VB/VBA to search Outlook messages and extract specific data into Excel worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826158/using-vb-vba-to-search-outlook-messages-and-extract-specific-data-into-excel-wor) which go through the message body to pick/search something. In my scenario, I want to consolidate both but I'm not able to come up with a basic script. Could someone give me pointers in consolidating the two and help me achieve my target of opening URLs from message body whenever a new mail arrives in Outlook mailbox. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub LaunchURL(itm As MailItem)

    Dim bodyString As String
    Dim bodyStringSplitLine
    Dim bodyStringSplitWord
    Dim splitLine
    Dim splitWord

    bodyString = itm.Body
    bodyStringSplitLine = Split(bodyString, vbCrLf)

    For Each splitLine In bodyStringSplitLine
        bodyStringSplitWord = Split(splitLine, " ")

        For Each splitWord In bodyStringSplitWord
            If Left(splitWord, 7) = "http://" Then
                Shell ("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" & " " & splitWord)
            End If
        Next

    Next

    Set itm = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub test()
    Dim currItem As MailItem
    Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
    LaunchURL currItem
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Alpha, I thing that is little unsafe, even if your rule if only people from a particular domain for.
That is a good idea, when you check urlstring with variable you create (like link only from local intranet).

```
if splitWord like "my_company_internat_url" then '...
```